# css media queries correct sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

Im developing a site using media queries. the ones that im using are this ones:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px){
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1299px){
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px){
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px){
```

the problem that i have is that there are certain screen resolutions in laptops that made the screen look like this:
[image]

As you can see. The navigation section overlaps the main logo and the letters and the bottom   go over the main navigation menu. This happens basically on laptops screens that have a very big width and small height. Is there any way that i can target this resolution with media queries?

Comment: If you use percentages instead of pixels, it's much easier to prevent issues such as these!

Comment: Did you notice you've overlap of MQ between 1024px and 1199px? Both 2nd and 3rd MQ apply: that's not necessarily a bad thing or buggy, it depends on which CSS rules are in 2nd and 3rd MQ :) If you're unsure of the resolutio on these laptops, you can learn more with http://mydevice.io

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1300px){
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1299px){
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1199px){
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px){
```

You can do something like this in addition:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 900px) {
```

And just put the elements you need to target inside the media-query. You can have as many media-queries as you'd like and target only the elements you need to.

It may be too late now, but I would recommend using `min-width` only in the future for most of your media-queries so you aren't reproducing some of the same code.